# Resize bound NFS volume in OpenShift Origin

Tags: nfs, openshift-origin

I have a Jenkins server running on OpenShift Origin 1.1
The pod is using persistent storage using NFS. We have a pv of 3GB and a pvc on this volume. It's bound and Jenkins is using it. But when we perform:
`sudo du -sh /folder` we see our folder is 15GB. So we want to resize our persistent volume while it's still in use. How can we perform this?

EDIT: or is the best way to recreate the pv and pvc on the same folder as before. So all the data will remain in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a manual process and is entirely dependent on the storage provider and the filesystem with which the volume is formatted.

Suppose you have NFS that has enough space say 15 Gb and you have pv only of 3Gb then you can simply edit the pv to increase the size.

"oc edit pv [name]" works and you can edit the size of the volume.